# c# Focus() appears to trigger the Leave() method

Tags: c#, winforms

The last time I did any serious programming was 25 years ago in C with a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie. Please be gentle with an aging amateur!

In essence, it's the old nullable date picker thing. I have a solution working perfectly well with one exception. I am using a combination of a masked TextBox and a MonthCalendar. The masked TextBox simply displays any value (including null) from a data set and accepts values from the calendar. Pressing backspace in the calendar clears the masked TextBox. All This is very straightforward. All I need to do now is to hide the calendar when it loses focus. A simple example demonstrates the problem I have:

Create a form with a text box to take the initial focus, a masked text box and a hidden MonthCalendar. In the Enter event of the masked text box, I have the following code:

```
monthCalendar1.Visible = true;
monthCalendar1.Focus();
```

My intention was to put the following code into the Leave event of the MonthCalendar:

```
monthCalendar1.Visible = false;
```

For some reason, this code is triggered as soon as the calendar gets the focus and the calendar is hidden again immediately. Debugging confirms that this code is triggered. If the Leave event is empty, the MonthCalendar does indeed get the focus and retains it, because it is possible to navigate the calendar with the arrow keys.

Can anyone explain this behavior to an old fogey or, even better, give me a pointer to what I'm trying to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use the DateTimePicker control?  It looks like that's what you are trying to mimic.

Comment: I have to be able to clear it and return null. All I have read about nullable DateTimePickers has only served to confuse me thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work around is to delay the focus of the MonthCalendar control until after the Enter event is finished firing:

```
monthCalendar1.Visible = true;
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { monthCalendar1.Select(); }));
```

Comment: This does the business, of course - I expect nothing else from you guys - and thank you, but it does seem an odd way of cracking what I thought was a simple nut.

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding. For more information, see the WM_KILLFOCUS topic in the "Keyboard Input Reference" section, and the "Message Deadlocks" section of the "About Messages and Message Queues" topic in the MSDN library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx). They also talk about which events happen when you get in depending on how you get in :)

Comment: Ah, I had seen this, but assumed it meant the various events of the same control. That explains it. at least. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Cheers, if you think it answers your question, you can mark it as answered. You can also see if something better comes along. You could also upvote/downvote answers you find useful. Cheers, and keep on coding :)

Comment: :) The joys of being a new user I guess... Seems like @LarsTech gave you an answer that works, which is great.